# window.open freezing when called from onchange function in ios 6 Safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, ios6, onchange, window.open

```
<select id="myDropDown" onblur='launchSite()'>
    <option value="selectone" selected="true">Select One</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google </option>
    <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN </option>
    <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN </option>
</select>


<script>

function launchSite()  {
    var el = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
    var url = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    window.open(url);
}
 </script>
```

We have a web app that opens a new browser page when a certain values are selected from a dropdown.  This worked fine in all previously tested browsers including Safari on ios 5.  After the dropdown value is selected in ios 6, we get the Allow/Deny popup which is expected. But then after making a selection on the popup Safari totally freezes.  The strange thing is that this freezing does not happen every time. Only occasionally.  Is it possible this is a ios 6 bug?  I've tried `onblur()` like other questions have suggested but I still get ocassional freezing.  I am able to see the problem using the code above.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
function launchSite(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var el = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
        var url = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
        window.open(url);
    },100); }
```

Put this in the onchange event handler should solve the freezing problem

Comment: Typo in setTim**t**out. I tried to fix it but I couldn't find 5 other characters to fix! ;)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a very similar issue when trying to call:

```
window.open(url, '_self')
```

in Chrome and Safari.  Instead, define where you want to open the window to:

```
window.open(url, '_blank')
or
window.open(url, '_new')
```

However, if you want to open as '_self', or the current window, then just call:

```
windown.location.href = url;
```